# How come MD5 hash values are not reversible?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

One concept I've always wondered about is the use of cryptographic hash functions and values. I understand that these functions can generate a hash value that is unique and virtually impossible to reverse, but here's what I've always wondered:

If on my server, in PHP I produce:

```
md5("stackoverflow.com") = "d0cc85b26f2ceb8714b978e07def4f6e"
```

When you run that same string through an MD5 function, you get the same result on your PHP installation. A process is being used to produce some value, from some starting value.

Doesn't this mean that there is some way to deconstruct what is happening and reverse the hash value?

What is it about these functions that makes the resulting strings impossible to retrace?

Comment: A simple example of non reversible value for example is modulo. For example 10 % 3 = 1, but you can't reverse the 1 to 10 as it could also be 4

Comment: If you could reconstruct the data you'd have the most efficient lossless compression algorithm ever :)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The input material can be an infinite length, where the output is always 128 bits long.  This means that an infinite number of input strings will generate the same output.

If you pick a random number and divide it by 2 but only write down the remainder, you'll get either a 0 or 1 -- even or odd, respectively.  Is it possible to take that 0 or 1 and get the original number?

Comment: That is to say, neither number --> remainder nor string --> md5 are "injective functions".

Comment: Federico, surely you mean that neither are bijective functions? They are both injective.

Comment: moocha: Injective means 1 to 1. The MD5 is certainly not 1 to 1, as the domain is larger than the range.

Another point worth noting is that given a MD5 checksum, it's very hard to find even one string that hashes to it. Might be worth adding to the answer for clarification.

Comment: You state that "an infinite number of strings will generate the same output." Isn't that contradictory to the statement in the question that these types of functions "generate a hash value that is unique."  In your random number example produces a value that is almost never unique.  I'm confused.

Comment: It's impossible to have a hash function that generates unique values.  You're mapping an infinite number of values into a finite number of values, which guarantees collisions.

Comment: I'd suggest that your answer does not address the key point.  As biozinc mentioned, what's important for a secure password hash is that you can't find any input that creates the output, not that you can't find the original input.  On that note, MD5 is not necessarily as secure as it could be (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities).

Comment: The same non-injectivity property would be valid for `substr($input."                ", 0, 16)` (with 16 spaces), but this certainly is not a good hash function (here the preimage attacks are trivial).

Comment: Does MD5 truly operate on an infinitely long input value?  Or is it just that there are infinitely many possible input values (each of finite length)?

Comment: Right, but based on the information in your answer, it would seem that hash functions are inherently vulnerable to collisions.  I realize that MD6 is notoriously so, but ones generally understood to be secure supposedly aren't.  How do you make the leap from a `mod 2` operation to constructing an actual hash function that doesn't have a 50% chance of two randomly given inputs colliding?

Comment: @DaveL., I think that once you cap the length, you automatically cap the number of permutations that could conceivably fit within that length constraint.  Think about it: if you have `X` bits as a maximum length, that represents a number expressed in base 2. If you forget that its binary for a second and just think about decimal ("normal") numbers, and say that you have 8 digits in which to express a number, the highest number that can be expressed is going to be `99999999` (https://youtu.be/0Ba9HAKxw9M), and the lowest would be `00000000`...

Comment: @DaveL.   There are then only `100000000` numbers that can ever be expressed in that many places, and the same holds true when you're dealing with binary.

Comment: @adlwalrus I don't think you understood this distinction.  For example, there are an infinite number of integers, but every integer is of finite length, or takes a finite number of bits to represent.  Similarly, I would expect that MD5 can operate on an infinite number of possible input values, but not on an input value of infinite length (it would never terminate or produce output).

Comment: Beiing a total cryptonoob and all, I'm not really a qualified person to answer the question, and I don't know the answer for sure, but I would be willing to bet that there is no cap on input value length, and I'll tell you why.  There's a cap on input length for RSA asymmetric encryption, but it's overcome with a hack by using symmetric and then asymmetrically encrypting the symmetric key, which is of finite length.  If there were any such limitation, I'm sure that the developers of any hash algorithm would find a similarly clever coping mechanism for such cases, like breaking it up into...

Comment: ...blocks, and then concatenating and hashing the hashes of those blocks until it's within the input length limit.  Given that I'm not a cryptographer and I could think of that on the spot, I'm sure the hash devs could have thought of something better and I can't really see any reason why they might not use it, so like I said I'd be willing to bet that they did use something to the effect of what I came up with.

Comment: Hash functions *are* inherently vulnerable to collisions; good hash functions are simply more evenly distributed and thus their collision potential is closer to optimal.  No hash is invulnerable to collisions.

Comment: @DaveL.: He's using "infinite" in an informal way to mean "unlimited".

Comment: This answer is incorrect and goes very far in conflating a function that nearly is a truly-irreversible function like `f(x) = 1` with a hash function used for, say, passwords.

If you have several candidates for passwords like `password` and `8ZDEyCJ!WM` and `tXhN7TW&zq`, it's not exactly hard to figure out which is the original. This isn't just a theoretical thing: such statistical regularities in human language are used to crack all kinds of cryptographic things.

Comment: Olathe: By that regard, f(x) = x % 5 is reversible.  What you're saying is that, given f(x), y=f(x'), and a set of possible x's, you can find the x' that matches y; that's completely true.  But it doesn't make the function reversible in any way.  Hashes -- even broken hashes -- are irreversible.  That doesn't mean it isn't possible to bruteforce f() or find a preimage attack against it.

Comment: @CodyBrocious The "goodness" of a hash function is not mainly measured by its evenness of distribution (a simple remainder function might do better), but by the hardness (in terms of computing time) of finding collisions, preimages, or other attacks.

Answer (score 54):

If hash functions such as MD5 were reversible then it would have been a watershed event in the history of data compression algorithms! Its easy to see that if MD5 were reversible then arbitrary chunks of data of arbitrary size could be represented by a mere 128 bits without any loss of information. Thus you would have been able to reconstruct the original message from a 128 bit number regardless of the size of the original message.

Comment: think how quick it would be to download linux distros if you could just get the md5 instead :)

Comment: @Colin Pickard: we wouldn't be *downloading* linux distros any more, we would be *writing them down*. :)

Answer (score 39):

Contrary to what the most upvoted answers here emphasize, the **non-injectivity** (i.e. that there are several strings hashing to the same value) of a cryptographic hash function caused by the difference between large (potentially infinite) input size and fixed output size **is not the important point** – actually, we prefer hash functions where those collisions happen as seldom as possible.

Consider this function (in PHP notation, as the question):

```
function simple_hash($input) {
     return bin2hex(substr(str_pad($input, 16), 0, 16));
}
```

This appends some spaces, if the string is too short, and then takes the first 16 bytes of the string, then encodes it as hexadecimal. It has the same output size as an MD5 hash (32 hexadecimal characters, or 16 bytes if we omit the bin2hex part).

```
print simple_hash("stackoverflow.com");
```

This will output:

```
737461636b6f766572666c6f772e636f6d
```

This function also has the same non-injectivity property as highlighted by Cody's answer for MD5: We can pass in strings of any size (as long as they fit into our computer), and it will output only 32 hex-digits. Of course it can't be injective.

But in this case, it is trivial to find a string which maps to the same hash (just apply `hex2bin` on your hash, and you have it). If your original string had the length 16 (as our example), you even will get this original string. Nothing of this kind should be possible for MD5, even if you know the length of the input was quite short (other than by trying all possible inputs until we find one that matches, e.g. a brute-force attack).

**The important assumptions for a cryptographic hash function are:**

- it is hard to find any string producing a given hash (preimage resistance)
- it is hard to find any different string producing the same hash as a given string (second preimage resistance)
- it is hard to find any pair of strings with the same hash (collision resistance)

Obviously my `simple_hash` function fulfills neither of these conditions. (Actually, if we restrict the input space to "16-byte strings", then my function becomes injective, and thus is even provable second-preimage resistant and collision resistant.)

There now exist collision attacks against MD5 (e.g. it is possible to produce a pair of strings, even with a given same prefix, which have the same hash, with quite some work, but not impossible much work), so you shouldn't use MD5 for anything critical.
There is not yet a preimage attack, but attacks will get better.

**To answer the actual question:**

> What is it about these functions that makes the
>   resulting strings impossible to retrace?

What MD5 (and other hash functions build on the Merkle-Damgard construction) effectively do is applying an encryption algorithm with the message as the key and some fixed value as the "plain text", using the resulting ciphertext as the hash. (Before that, the input is padded and split in blocks, each of this blocks is used to encrypt the output of the previous block, XORed with its input to prevent reverse calculations.)

Modern encryption algorithms (including the ones used in hash functions) are made in a way to make it hard to recover the key, even given both plaintext and ciphertext (or even when the adversary chooses one of them).
They do this generally by doing lots of bit-shuffling operations in a way that each output bit is determined by each key bit (several times) and also each input bit. That way you can only easily retrace what happens inside if you know the full key and either input or output.

For MD5-like hash functions and a preimage attack (with a single-block hashed string, to make things easier), you only have input and output of your encryption function, but not the key (this is what you are looking for).

Comment: Yes, I know that this is a quite late answer, but the accepted answer should not be let standing this way.

Comment: I think your criticisms have some merit but you have failed to answer the actual question "What is it about these functions that makes the resulting strings impossible to retrace?" 

Your answer focuses on the qualities a cryptographic hash should have but has zero explanation of how they are implemented by md5.

You could state the exact algorithm for computing MD5 sums here to show how it is not reversible but the other answers do provide a simpler explanation without going into the nitty-gritties.

Comment: (cont...) 2. These explanations use "Math" to show a fundamental problem due to which such operations loose information and become irreversible.

Comment: @SandeepDatta I added some paragraphs about this.

Comment: While other answer in this thread are more technically correct, this answer is the most useful. The non-injective function f(x)=1 is non-reversible but uninteresting. The usefulness of hashing lies in preimage resistance where it is difficult to find *any* input yielding a specific output.

Answer (score 18):

Cody Brocious's answer is the right one. Strictly speaking, you cannot "invert" a hash function because many strings are mapped to the same hash. Notice, however, that either finding *one* string that gets mapped to a given hash, or finding *two* strings that get mapped to the same hash (i.e. a *collision*), would be major breakthroughs for a cryptanalyst. The great difficulty of both these problems is the reason why good hash functions are useful in cryptography.

Answer (score 12):

MD5 does not create a unique hash value; the goal of MD5 is to quickly produce a value that changes significantly based on a minor change to the source.

E.g.,

```
"hello" -> "1ab53"
"Hello" -> "993LB"
"ZR#!RELSIEKF" -> "1ab53"
```

(Obviously that's not actual MD5 encryption)

Most hashes (if not all) are also non-unique; rather, they're unique *enough*, so a collision is highly improbable, but still possible.

Answer (score 9):

A good way to think of a hash algorithm is to think of resizing an image in Photoshop... say you have a image that is 5000x5000 pixels and you then resize it to just 32x32. What you have is still a representation of the original image but it is much much smaller and has effectively "thrown away" certain parts of the image data to make it fit in the smaller size. So if you were to resize that 32x32 image back up to 5000x5000 all you'd get is a blurry mess. However because a 32x32 image is not that large it would be theoretically conceivable that another image could be downsized to produce the exact same pixels!

That's just an analogy but it helps understand what a hash is doing.

Comment: While image-resizing is a lossy process, it is still quite easy to produce an image in the original 5000×5000 size which will (when applying the shrinking function again) reduce to the same 32×32 image. Finding such a preimage should be **hard** for a good hash function.

Answer (score 4):

A hash collision is much more likely than you would think. Take a look at the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox) to get a greater understanding of why that is.

Comment: There are 365 possible birthday values, which is between 2^8 and 2^9. A 128-bit hash has 2^128 possible values -- 2^120 times as many. Yes, collisions are more likely than you might intuit, but they are still astronomically unlikely.

Comment: You'll need about 2^64 different values to have a good chance at a hash collision. Still quite some.

Answer (score 4):

As the number of possible input files is larger than the number of 128-bit outputs, it's impossible to uniquely assign an MD5 hash to each possible.

Cryptographic hash functions are used for checking data integrity or digital signatures (the hash being signed for efficiency). Changing the original document should therefore mean the original hash doesn't match the altered document.

These criteria are sometimes used:

1. Preimage resistance: for a given hash function and given hash, it should be difficult to find an input that has the given hash for that function.
2. Second preimage resistance: for a given hash function and input, it should be difficult to find a second, different, input with the same hash.
3. Collision resistance: for a given has function, it should be difficult to find two different inputs with the same hash.

These criterial are chosen to make it difficult to find a document that matches a given hash, otherwise it would be possible to forge documents by replacing the original with one that matched by hash. (Even if the replacement is gibberish, the mere replacement of the original may cause disruption.)

Number 3 implies number 2.

As for MD5 in particular, it has been shown to be flawed:
[How to break MD5 and other hash functions](http://www.infosec.sdu.edu.cn/uploadfile/papers/How%20to%20Break%20MD5%20and%20Other%20Hash%20Functions.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

But this is where rainbow tables come into play.
Basically it is just a large amount of values hashed separetely and then the result is saved to disk. Then the reversing bit is "just" to do a lookup in a very large table.

Obviously this is only feasible for a subset of all possible input values but if you know the bounds of the input value it might be possible to compute it.

Comment: Ahh yes. I enjoyed reading Jeff's post on Hash Tables (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000949.html), and this thread has helped in the understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese scientist have found a way called "chosen-prefix collisions" to make a conflict between two different strings.

Here is an example: http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/fastcoll_v1.0.0.5.exe.zip
The source code: http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/fastcoll_v1.0.0.5_source.zip

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand what all the most voted answers meant is to actually try to revert the MD5 algorithm. I remember I tried to revert the **MD5crypt** algorithm some years ago, not to recover the original message because it is clearly impossible, but just to generate a message that would produce the same hash as the original hash. This, at least theoretically, would provide me a way to login to a Linux device that stored the user:password in the /etc/passwd file using the generated message (password) instead of using the original one. Since both messages would have the same resulting hash, the system would recognize my password (generated from the original hash) as valid. That didn't work at all. After several weeks, if I remember correctly, the use of **salt** in the initial message killed me. I had to produce not only a valid initial message, but a salted valid initial message, which I was never able to do. But the knowledge that I got from this experiment was nice.

Comment: If you were able to generate an input that produced the given MD5 hash value in any reasonably efficient fashion, that would be a big deal to the crypto community and should be published.  That's completely independent of whether a particular input was salted.

Answer (score 1):

As most have already said MD5 was designed for variable length data streams to be hashed to a fixed length chunk of data, so a single hash is shared by many input data streams.

However if you ever did need to find out the original data from the checksum, for example if you have the hash of a password and need to find out the original password, it's often quicker to just google (or whatever searcher you prefer) the hash for the answer than to brute force it. I have successfully found out a few passwords using this method.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a cryptographic hash function should not be invertible and should have the least collisions possible.

Regarding your question: it is a one way hash. The input (irrespective of length) will generate a fixed size output, which will be padded based on algo (512 bit boundary for MD5). The information is compressed (lost) and practically not possible to generate from reverse transforms.

Additional info on MD5: it is vulnerable to collisions. I have gone through this article recently,
http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/Nostradamus/

Open source code for crypto hash implementations (MD5 and SHA) can be found at Mozilla code.
(freebl library).

Answer (score 0):

Now a days MD5 hashes or any other hashes for that matter are pre computed for all possible strings and stored for easy access. Though in theory MD5 is not reversible but using such databases you may find out which text resulted in a particular hash value.

For example try the following hash code at http://gdataonline.com/seekhash.php to find out what text i used to compute the hash

```
aea23489ce3aa9b6406ebb28e0cda430
```

Comment: Ah, yes, the hash of a commonplace 7-letter word. Now use it to figure out this 11-word song lyric with whitespace and punctuation: 9f2c08d4e6158bd4854b15be50c8daa8. See you in several millenia.

Comment: 6fba2bbab8a8366309bf67c7df12c622? Hint: it might be the OEM version of a specific version of Mac OS X!

Comment: @Tim Keating, @scherand: Just pointing out the weakness of hash algorithms, because hash of a string is always same we don't necessarily need to crack the algorithm to figure out the actual string.

Comment: But that's not what you said. You said that hashes are "precomputed for all possible strings and stored for easy access" which is patently false (the set of "all possible strings" is infinite... and even the set of "all plausible strings" is really, really large). IMHO this misrepresents how easy it is to do a dictionary attack against a reasonable passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

f(x) = 1 is irreversible. Hash functions aren't irreversible.

This is actually ***required*** for them to fulfill their function of determining whether someone possesses an uncorrupted copy of the hashed data. This brings susceptibility to brute force attacks, which are quite powerful these days, particularly against MD5.

There's also confusion here and elsewhere among people who have mathematical knowledge but little cipherbreaking knowledge. Several ciphers simply XOR the data with the keystream, and so you could say that a ciphertext corresponds to all plaintexts of that length because you could have used any keystream.

However, this ignores that a reasonable plaintext produced from the seed `password` is much, much more likely than another produced by the seed `Wsg5Nm^bkI4EgxUOhpAjTmTjO0F!VkWvysS6EEMsIJiTZcvsh@WI$IH$TYqiWvK!%&Ue&nk55ak%BX%9!NnG%32ftud%YkBO$U6o` to the extent that anyone claiming that the second was a possibility would be laughed at.

In the same way, if you're trying to decide between the two potential passwords `password` and `Wsg5Nm^bkI4EgxUO`, it's not as difficult to do as some mathematicians would have you believe.

Comment: Where do you get your *Most ciphers simply XOR the data with the keystream* knowledge? This is true for stream ciphers, but there are block ciphers, too, and they don't work this way.

Answer (score -5):

I like all the various arguments.
It is obvious the real value of hashed values is simply to provide human-unreadable placeholders for  strings such as passwords.
It has no specific enhanced security benefit.
Assuming an attacker gained access to a table with hashed passwords, he/she can:

- Hash a password of his/her own choice and place the results inside the password table if he/she has writing/edit rights to the table.
- Generate hashed values of common passwords and test the existence of similar hashed values in the  password table.

In  this  case  weak  passwords  cannot  be  protected  by  the  mere  fact  that  they are  hashed.

Comment: The real value of "hashed values" is not to provide human-unreadable placeholders. If 'password1' hashed to 'newval', does that still not *hide* the value in a similar way, although the hash is readable and meaningful? Furthermore, passwords are a BAD example, because they should NEVER be hashed. Assuming the attacker had write access to said database, that is definitely a possibility.
However it seems you are merely discarding the proper use for such hashing functions, one example is outlined in the many answers above - message integrity. It is the reason I'm on this thread today, actually.