# Get original string from md5

Tags: codeigniter

I want to return my original string from MD5, which is stored in database.

Here I have stored the password, it is- dipti and encrypted as 
95e62d2c1c1cdab7efda7d2cdb64cf85

```
$password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
```

Now I want to show the original string as dipti.

Comment: before encrypting store original in the new field, bcoz it is not possible to decrypt from md5

Comment: Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2717958/1929665

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can it be impossible to "decrypt" an MD5 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717950/how-can-it-be-impossible-to-decrypt-an-md5-hash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Comment: md5 is a  hashing technique and it is irreversible

Comment: You fail to understand why it's important that you can't extract a password from a hash. It's an unsafe action, and MD5 for passwords is also unsafe. Please see the PHP documentation for password_hash http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a hashing technique. You cannot decrypt it. You can compare the MD5 value with the another MD5 value to check matches (mostly in the case of password verification...)

The following site try to make the value from the MD5 value to original text
http://www.md5online.org/md5-decrypt.html

Comment: How can you say `You cannot decrypt it` and then say `The following site decrypts the MD5 value to original text `?

Comment: That's my bad. Updated the answer. Still, Hashes are one way - they are irreversible.

MD5 hashes are also used to ensure the data integrity of files. Because the MD5 hash algorithm always produces the same output for the same given input, users can compare a hash of the source file with a newly created hash of the destination file to check that it is intact and unmodified.