# CryptoJS.SHA256 help needed

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am new to `crypto`, please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
var seed = "adb6f118edd6ca21cd88c2709b5b395266c0b3d71bd3c55bac875a31017c29fa"
var seed_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(seed).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

console.log(seed_hash);
```

The result of `seed_hash` is

```
"ead4c97002cdd8e9d60199fb23a2173fbe4065c55855608a2d1dee38891513a6"
```

My question is, how to convert it back to

```
"adb6f118edd6ca21cd88c2709b5b395266c0b3d71bd3c55bac875a31017c29fa"
```

and print it in the console as text.

Comment: You can't reverse a hash

Comment: Read up on [hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). They are designed to be irreversible.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not possible to reverse a cryptographic hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603849/why-is-it-not-possible-to-reverse-a-cryptographic-hash)

Comment: you need to compare two hash to say if it's the same informations

Answer (score 7):

You cannot, SHA256 is an hash algorithm and it is known to be irreversible.

So, if you have to check up for example the password stored in DB and the password inserted in a form, you have to:

- store the SHA256 in your DB
- compare the stored password with the SHA256 of the actual inserted password

For same content the result will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: All true but SHA256 (any simple hash) is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iteration over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force

Comment: Thank you for your help.