# What info can be extracted from my password hashing function? Is it reversible?

Tags: php, security, hash

With the following `switch case` method

```
switch ($crypt_type) {
      case "MD5": $crypted_pass = md5($password); break;
      case "SHA1": $crypted_pass = sha1($password); break;

      case "DESMD5":
//jpap
//      $salt = substr($crypt_type, 0, 11);
        $salt = substr($p_password, 0, 11);
//jpap
        $crypted_pass = crypt($password, $salt);
        break;

      case "CRYPT":
//jpap
//      $salt = substr($crypt_type, 0, 2);
        $salt = substr($p_password, 0, 2);
//jpap
        $crypted_pass = crypt($password, $salt);
        break;

      default: 
        $crypted_pass = sha1($password); break;
    }
```

this is the hashed password it was produced

```
$1$lwnY.pgz$rm4Bwn0XmK7k4QawHi8Cz0
```

What info can be extracted by this? Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash function cannot be reversed which is why they are ideal for storing password. For explanation why is that so, check out [this SO Question how-come-md5-hash-values-are-not-reversible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330207/how-come-md5-hash-values-are-not-reversible) and see the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The original password cannot be extracted from this, that's by definition. From the provided string, I can deduct that `$CRYPT_TYPE` is crypt and the used algorithm is md5 with salt `1wnY.pgz`. You should not use a part of the password as salt for `crypt` as this is visible in the result.

It is safe in the sense that the original value cannot be calculated from the hash.