# how to decrypt a md5 data in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

I have a table which is having md5 encrypted data in it. I have to copy that data in another table but in decrypted form. How can i do that in mysql query??

Answer (score 4):

You cannot decrypt an md5 hashed string, since it is a one way algorithm. But they can be converted using reverse lookup using mysql. You can refer various online decrypts to find a best solution.

Comment: then how can i get original pattern from md5 column?

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is not a reversible encryption algorithm. It's a [one-way hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). The aim of a hash is to allow you to verify (with some degree of uncertainty) whether someone had the same original information as was used to create the hash. It does *not* allow you to get back from the hash to the original information.

Comment: then how can i get original pattern from md5 column?

Comment: @151291: You don't. If you need the original data, you shouldn't have just hashed it.

Comment: i did not get, can i get or not? what is hash?

Comment: @151291: There's a link in my answer explaining it. Please read it.

Answer (score 2):

MD5, as others have said here, is [not reversible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330207/how-come-md5-hash-values-are-not-reversible). Having said that, there are databases that contain sort of dictionaries to allow reverse lookup on MD5 hashes.

Check it out: http://tools.benramsey.com/md5/

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Other_vulnerabilities).

Comment: These tools are just like old cracking tools. In fact I have tried some examples on the url you sent and no one has been decrypted correctly (in fact the same MD5 can correspond to several different origins). The response should be "hashing algorithms are not reversible".

Comment: Well, that's the first statement on my response. I'm just pointing out the fact that these dictionaries exist. They are not actually decryption tools, so they will certainly not "reverse" every hash you throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

NO, md5 data can not be decrypted.

Answer (score 0):

No,

MD5 is a HASH algorithm so, it is not possible to decrypt. To test if some value is correct, you compare the MD5(value) to stored MD5, but it is impossible to extract the original value from MD5.

Answer (score 0):

If you decrypt the data from MysQL what would be the point of crypting it?
You can only compare to a MD5 password with uncrypted data.

You can ofcourse crack the MD5, read http://alan.blog-city.com/cracking_mysqls_md5_function__within_seconds.htm

But you kinda missed the whole point of encrypting your password :/

Comment: The links deos not work anymore can you fix it ??