# How to get the original password from md5 value of password from database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored a password in database using md5. I wanted to retrieve the original password from the md5 value of password.Can anyone tell how to retrieve the original password from the md5 value.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come MD5 hash values are not reversible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330207/how-come-md5-hash-values-are-not-reversible)

Comment: md5 is a cryptographic hash function. It's designed to prevent you from retrieving the orginal password.

Comment: Just google the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Md5 is irreversible.

Answer (score 0):

No way (almost). This is what md5 is designed for (although it has some weakness, better in this matter are the algorithms of the sha family, and in there sha2 and sha3). The basic idea of any cryptograhpic hash is to create results such that for different inputs the hash value differs with high probability, but reconstructing the original input from the hash is as difficult as possible.

There are collision attacks known to md5, but you cannot be sure to get the original password back, if you succeed, only an equivalent one in the sense that both produce the same hash. I do not assume that you want to try doing so, though...