# How to recover your password forgotten if password hash by MD5

Tags: vb.net, hash, md5

i made 2 program client and server and enter secure number if user forgotten password recover it by enter secure number it  work correctly but if hash password by MD5 can not able to recover password by secure number i enter it and below is code about it

```
 ' query database, check if username and password are correct
    Dim mysqlDB As New mysql
    Dim userDB As String = mysqlDB.prepareQuery(arr(0).ToString)
    Dim passDB As String = mysqlDB.prepareQuery(arr(1).ToString)
    Dim query As String = "select * from users where userName='" + userDB + "' and password = '" + passDB + "'"
    mysqlDB.QueryDB(query)
    Dim found As Boolean = False

    ' read results
    While mysqlDB.reader.Read()
        username = mysqlDB.reader.GetString(1)
        password = mysqlDB.reader.GetString(2)
        clientPublicKey = mysqlDB.reader.GetString(3)
        found = True
    End While
    mysqlDB.CloseDB()

    If found = False Then   ' if not found check SecID

        query = "select password from users where userName='" + userDB + "' and SecID = '" + passDB + "'"
        mysqlDB.QueryDB(query)
        found = False
        ' read results
        While mysqlDB.reader.Read()
            password = "Your Password: " & mysqlDB.reader.GetString(0)
            Sbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password)
            found = True
        End While
        mysqlDB.CloseDB()
        If found = False Then   ' if not found send error message
            Sbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Wrong username or password")
        End If

        stream.Write(Sbytes, 0, Sbytes.Length)
        stream.Close()
        tcpClient.Close()
        Exit Sub

    End If
    ' close DB connection
    mysqlDB.CloseDB()
```

Comment: The *whole point* of storing hashed passwords is that it makes recovery prohibitively difficult.

Comment: Execute a method with all possible password variations, which generate MD5 hash and compare with saved one until you find match - this approach called "Brute force" :)

Comment: @Fabio i not want to use brute force .. i wand to recovery password depended on secure id number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come MD5 hash values are not reversible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330207/how-come-md5-hash-values-are-not-reversible)

Comment: What would be the point of hashing if it could be easily undone?

Comment: @Plutonix , no i want to ensure the user recovery password if forggotten becasuse i bult system of email and hash password to prevent attack from obtain password

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you could revert MD5 hash back to original password the answer is: "No, you cannot do that".

Comment: why cannot able to do that

Comment: Here's a pretty good answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/330210

Comment: @FatimaIE, please, mark my answer as accepted answer as it is the only answer and correct answer. Thanks! :)